# I need help fixing this code

Tags: php, mysql, session

So, I made a PHP page/link checker, which should not allow an user to visit/redirect to a page if isn't passed certain minutes from last visit/redirect.

The problem is, the user is being redirected to the page ALWAYS even if he already did it 1 min ago and the timer is 7 min (example). The timer is setted into MySQL as minutes.

can't figure out what is wrong in the code

this is the first page:

```
<?php
session_start();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_records";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$records = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$records[] = $row;
}
foreach ($records as $record) {
$now = new DateTime();
if (!array_key_exists($record, $_SESSION['records']) || ($now->getTimestamp()-$_SESSION['records'][$record]) <= 600) {
    echo "<td><center>".$record['id']."</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>".$record['name']."</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>".$record['link']."</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>".$record['delay']."</center></td>";`
} else {
    // link disabled
}
}
?>
```

and this is the page the users are redirected to, to check the timer, and in case redirect them to the link.

```
$waiting_time = $delay * 60; //calculate delay time in seconds

if (!array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION['records'])) {

$_SESSION['records'][$id] = $now->getTimestamp();
header("Location: $link");
exit();

} elseif (array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION['records']) && ($now->getTimestamp()-$_SESSION['records'][$id]) >= $waiting_time) {

echo "Looks like you already visited this page";

} elseif (array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION['records']) && ($now->getTimestamp()-$_SESSION['records'][$id]) < $waiting_time) {

$_SESSION['records'][$id] = $now->getTimestamp();
header("Location: $link");
exit();

}
```

The problem is, the user is being redirected to the $link ALWAYS, even if he already visited, and the time of delay isn't passed.

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: 1: Be ready for people who are going to say 'use mysqli' or 'use PDO' which you should do. 2: Could you var_dump the substraction of your timestamps ? I expect the cast from string to int/float/long/double/whatever not to be done.

Comment: 1. Heh 2. If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Don't forget to use prepared statements in PDO, newbies forget most of the time

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_name` without a `WHERE` or `LIMIT` clause is going to get you into trouble when this table accumulates more than a trivial amount of data. You're loading *everything* into memory to see if a key exists when what you want is `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE id=?`

Comment: as suggested i var_dumped the value of ($now->getTimestamp()-$_SESSION['records'][$id]) and returns a number like: 495878454

Answer (score 0):

DRY, you can write your if/elseif statements much easier:

```
if (array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION['records']) && ($now->getTimestamp()-$_SESSION['records'][$id]) < $waiting_time) {
    echo "Looks like you already visited this page";
} else {
    $_SESSION['records'][$id] = $now->getTimestamp();
    header("Location: $link");
    exit();
}
```

Now, if you look at it you'll see there are two things to check at first:

1. Is `$_SESSION['records']` not empty (maybe session wasn't intialized on second page?) - `var_dump ($_SESSION['records'])` - what's in there?
2. what's the result of `($now->getTimestamp()-$_SESSION['records'][$id])` and what's in `$waiting_time` variable - var_dump it

Don't forget to call `exit()` after dumping the code and before redirection or simply comment `location ()` lines, otherwise you'll see nothing

Third possibility (you'll know this is the case if you don't see var_dump printout) is that your browser remembers 301 redirection and when you go second time to same address it redirects automatically without calling your script - restart your browser or try different one.

Comment: the result of ($now->getTimestamp()-$_SESSION['records'][$id]) returns a number like: 495878454   and the $waiting_time returns a number like: 1900  or so.. thats why i can't figure out.  them is working actually, or at least, them aren't empty

Comment: Conditions for redirect are: no record in session or waiting time (`($now->getTimestamp()-$_SESSION['records'][$id])` result) is LESS THAN defined by $waiting_time variable. So if you want NOT to redirect for 30 minutes - reverse the condition (first and second elsif conditions should be switched), cause now you told the code to redirect if <30min